# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChainContents

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a war application (spring + jsf1.2/richfaces + hibernate) running on my was8.5 server, when i try to access http://localhost:9080/name_app/login.xhtml, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` coming from the server internal source, below is the log trace of the error :

```
[28/01/16 09:45:06:325 WET]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -RE ProbeId:1123 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@9afb2765
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChainContents(WebAppFilterManager.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="Auth_Super_Admin_WEBAPP" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 

    <description>Antij Project web.xml</description>
    <display-name>Antij -AuthForte-User-Admin-web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>classic</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- added , but doesn't affect-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableViewStateIdRendering</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/web-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>server</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param> -->
    <context-param>
        <description>
        State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>


 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/components/antij.taglib.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
<!--   -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Set the size limit for uploaded files.
Format: 10 - 10 bytes
10k - 10 KB
10m - 10 MB
1g - 1 GB
</description>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Set the threshold size - files below this limit are stored
in memory, files above this limit are stored on disk.
Format: 10 - 10 bytes
10k - 10 KB
10m - 10 MB
1g - 1 GB
</description>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100k</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>*.xhtml</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    <!-- listener to load spring beans -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/modules/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!--
    <resource-ref>
        <description>My Data Source.</description>
        <res-ref-name>acs_3ds</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>-->

    <!-- resource ref for websphere -->

     <resource-ref>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
       <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>

    <persistence-unit-ref>
       <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/authentification-forte-user-admin-entityManager-pu</persistence-unit-ref-name>
       <persistence-unit-name>authentification-forte-user-admin-entityManager-pu</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

According to the log trace it didn't originate in own code, I think it's about some misconfiguration in web.xml , Am not sure.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jens , but I can't figure out what's the common things between my post and the one that you suggested.

Comment: This porblem may be caused by some misconfiguration in my `web.xml` (probably with the filter-mapping ), @BalusC have you any idea ?

Comment: Regardless of misconfiguration, NullPointerException probably should not happen within the application server's code.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Like @BrettKail said, you should open a PMR with IBM. Also, you should consider capturing the WebContainer MustGather and adding that to the PMR:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384592

Comment: Have you an example of basic configuration for datasource, persistence unit, .. that matched with websphere8.5

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same bug and found a solution.

Find which filter is causing this error by removing the filters from web.xml one at a time until you don't get this error.

Then rename that filter in both `<filter><filter-name> and <filter-mapping><filter-name>`. Note that filter-name can be any string but that values must match. It does not need to be the same name as your filter class name only `<filter-class>` needs to be the same name as your class.

Now try running it and it should work. You should now be able to rename your filter to it's original name.